# Нейросеть для обработки одномерного массива

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Добрый вечер,
Необходимо создать нейросеть для определения зависимости на последовательности.
Например у нас есть эталонная зависимость

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

И также у нас есть входные данные, которые могут быть смещены:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

На выходе хотелось бы иметь какое-то число от 0 до 1 с вероятностью совпадения.
Буду рад услышать и увидеть любой материал, ссылки, а еще лучше псевдо- или обычный код.

Comment: Поздноват комментарий, но классификаторы здесь могут быть излишни. Массив можно представить как вектор в некотором пространстве. Тогда мерой "похожести" будет значение косинуса между векторами. Для данного примера это 0.2

Answer (score 7):

Тема определения зависимы ли (перефразировано - насколько похожи) два набора данных друг от друга широка и довольно плотно исследована. Иногда я сторонник простых решений и прежде чем переходить к "попсовым" классификаторам, лучше пройтись по списку старых-добрых чисто статистических (или иных) методов (коли у нас просто в общем виде есть только массивы). В вопросе не указан тип данных, поэтому я пройдусь наугад по всему, что приходит в голову. Характер данных здесь играет ключевую роль - именно от него и зависит выбранный метод.

Самое первое, что приходит в голову, когда говорят про зависимость какой-либо переменной от другой - [корреляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Коэффициент корреляция вы можете посчитать, используя [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) - этот метод вернет матрицу ковариации. Корреляция - базовый метод - есть гораздо более изощренные и, соответственно, сложные. Корреляция - супер крутая вещь. Всеядна, универсальна, проста как лопата - никогда не подведет. Твой лучший друг и товарищ на поприще анализа данных.

Иной подход - найти наибольшую общую подпоследовательность в ваших данных. Данный абзац здесь появился только из-за того, что было упомянуто, что данные могут быть сдвинуты. В этом случае применим [кольцевой хеш (rolling hash)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88) или любые иные методы поиска подпоследовательности. Однако, в общем случае, на случайных данных правило "сдвига" не будет выполняться.

Иная идея - самый что ни на есть обыкновенный [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2). Ваш пример:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
XOR
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
=
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Результатом имеем две единицы (то есть различающихся значений) из 11 - вот настолько две этих маски отличны (то есть данные одинаковы на `1 - 2 / 11 = 82%`). Операция настолька быстра и дешева, что быстрее не найдете. Однако, опять-таки - не универсальна.

Иной универсальный подход - косинус угла между векторами. Или же [cosine similarity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B8). Эта метрика изначально - мера "близости", похожести двух векторов (другой пример близости - Евклидово расстояние между ними). Также простая, классная вещь - единственный момент - ваши данные должны быть представимы как вектора. Вот есть [интересный пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa) использования этой меры для сравнения похожести двух строк. Для ваших данных эта мера дает ответ 0.8 (1 - 0.2). Также всмотритесь повнимательнее - данная мера очень похожа на корреляцию. И неспроста.

Вы можете посчитать "близость" данных используя [Метод Наименьших Квадратов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) (МНК). Он также прост, причем он даже проще лопаты - он прост как ее древко. Он также универсален.

Если ваши данные - это распределение вероятностей (это важно, метод не применим для обычных экспериментальных данных), то вам идеально подойдет [расстояние землекопа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).

Как видно, с методов определения "близости" ОЧЕНЬ много и я лишь мельком затронул известные мне - какой выбрать - зависит только от ваших данных. И даже для "сложных", типа звука, изображений, текста лучше для начала попробовать простецкие методы - они хорошо изучены, просты - они дадут вам какой-то результат мгновенно. Известно на каких данных они работают "плохо", а на каких хорошо. Также ИНС - это классификатор, а не определятор похожести. Погружаясь в нейронные сети без понимания того, что это такое и как с этим работать вы рискуете надолго забуксовать. Даже несмотря на наличие приятных абстракций в стиле Tensorflow. Все-таки каждому инструменту свое применение. Помните, если долго смотреть в бездну - бездна посмотрит на вас.

Comment: XOR со сдвигом или корреляция лучше всего.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите получать, введя 2 последовательности в некую модель, их схожесть между собой, то можно просто взять декартово расстояние между последовательностями чисел, т е корень суммы квадратов разностей, а затем нормировать до единицы. Для нормировки можно разделить на произведение длин векторов.

Если Вы хотите получить некую обученную модель, например, схожесть равна единице, если это инверсия, и у Вас при этом есть набор обучающих данных, то есть 2е выборки последовательностей X и X', то можно не использовать НС, а решить линейную систему уравнений W(X - X') = 5. W - это веса. Суть в том, что Вы можете взвесить 2е последовательности с первой половиной весов и со второй соответственно и получить по одному числу для каждой последовательности, потом посчитать коэффициент корреляции. Возможно при больших последовательностях  больших наборах данных поможет решение:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
n=7
m=2
W=np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]) # параметры линейной модели
X1=np.array([[1,1],[2,4],[3,6],[6,3],[5,8],[1,2],[9,1]]) # набор последовательностей 1

X2=np.array([[6,1],[3,4],[4,2],[0,7],[5,2],[2,4],[1,9]]) # набор последовательностей 2

A=np.array([ [0.0 for x in range(m*2)] for y in range(n)]) # левая часть системы уравнений
for i in range(m):
 for j in range(n):
  A[j,i]=X1[j,i]
  A[j,i+2]=-X2[j,i]
b=np.array([5.0]*n) # любые одинаковые числа - правая часть системы

# решение системы линейных уравнений --------
A1=A.T
Z=np.dot(A1,A)
Z=np.linalg.inv(Z)
W1=np.dot(Z,A1)
W=np.dot(W1,b)
# --------------------------------------------------



Y1=[0.0]*n
Y2=[0.0]*n


W1=[W[0],W[1]]

W2=[W[2],W[3]]
for i in range(n):
 x1=[0.0]*2
 for j in range(2):
  x1[j]=X1[i,j]
 Y1[i]=np.dot(x1,W1)
 x2=[0.0]*2
 for j in range(2):
  x2[j]=X2[i,j]
 Y2[i]=np.dot(x2,W2)
# формируем 2е выборки чисел по 2м выборкам последовательностей

c=np.array([0.0]*n)
c1=np.array([0.0]*n)
c2=np.array([0.0]*n)
av1=np.mean(Y1)
av2=np.mean(Y2)
#ковариация
for i in range(n):
 c[i]=(Y1[i]-av1)*(Y2[i]-av2)
 c1[i]=(Y1[i]-av1)**2
 c2[i]=(Y2[i]-av2)**2
sum=np.sum(c)
# выводим коэффициент корреляции
print(sum/np.sqrt(np.sum(c1)*np.sum(c2))) # 0.95
```

Заинтересовала задача поиска корреляции наборов кортежей, поэтому ввожу изменения в ответ, т.к. решение совсем не выдерживает проблемы сингулярности матрицы. Для обоснования логики решения оставила предыдущий код, но изменяю количество весов. Сейчас предлагаю решение: W[X, .. ,-X'] = [5,5,5...].
Конкретно для Вашей задачи можно проходиться окном по массиву и собирать такие последовательности, находя веса и корреляции.
Если матрица все же является сингулярной - это значит, что все векторы одинаковы или приблизительно равны. Если у Вас именно такой случай, то тут может помочь градиентный спуск: Sum((wi*xij - wi*xij)^2) -> min, в цикле находите производную суммы по каждому весу и, вычитая антиградиент из весов минимизируете сумму.

Привожу пример, когда последовательность кортежей X является инверсией X'. Получилась корреляция -1. Здесь матричный вариант:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
n=7
m=2
W=np.array([0.0,0.0]) # параметры линейной модели
X1=np.array([[1,1],[2,4],[3,6],[6,3],[5,8],[1,2],[9,1]]) # набор последовательностей 1

X2=np.array([[1,1],[4,2],[6,3],[3,6],[8,5],[2,1],[1,9]]) # набор последовательностей 2

A=np.array([ [0.0 for x in range(m)] for y in range(n*2)]) # левая часть системы уравнений
for i in range(m):
 for j in range(n):
  A[j,i]=X1[j,i]
  A[j+n,i]=-X2[j,i]
b=np.array([5.0]*n*2) # любые одинаковые числа - правая часть системы

# решение системы линейных уравнений --------
A1=A.T
Z=np.dot(A1,A)
Z=np.linalg.inv(Z)
W1=np.dot(Z,A1)
W=np.dot(W1,b)
# --------------------------------------------------



Y1=[0.0]*n
Y2=[0.0]*n


for i in range(n):
 x1=[0.0]*2
 for j in range(2):
  x1[j]=X1[i,j]
 Y1[i]=np.dot(x1,W)
 x2=[0.0]*2
 for j in range(2):
  x2[j]=X2[i,j]
 Y2[i]=np.dot(x2,W)
# формируем 2е выборки чисел по 2м выборкам последовательностей

c=np.array([0.0]*n)
c1=np.array([0.0]*n)
c2=np.array([0.0]*n)
av1=np.mean(Y1)
av2=np.mean(Y2)
#ковариация
for i in range(n):
 c[i]=(Y1[i]-av1)*(Y2[i]-av2)
 c1[i]=(Y1[i]-av1)**2
 c2[i]=(Y2[i]-av2)**2
sum=np.sum(c)
# выводим коэффициент корреляции
print(sum/np.sqrt(np.sum(c1)*np.sum(c2))) # инверсия -0.(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если представить зависимость в виде строки символов то можно использовать алгоритмы нечеткого поиска  [Алгоритм Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению (и напрасно!) не было никакой активности по данному вопросу. 
Единственный ответ про алгоритм Левенштейна к сожалению не имеет отношения к вопросу.

В качестве ответа приведу ссылку на [статью](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/09/urban-sound-classification-neural-networks-tensorflow.html) с небольшими комментариями.
Используется разложение в спектр, поиск взаимосвязанного набора характерных точек - дескриптор отдаленно напоминающий Bag Of Words в OCR. Затем обучение НС дескрипторам образцов, и затем оперативное вычисление дескрипторов и запрос НС на поиск соответствия. Используется TensorFlow - интересно куда это активные спецы в этой области подевались, только что были :-)

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, что именно нужно. Что значит "данные смещены"? Смотрю на первый и второй вектор и не могу увидеть, каким образом смещены данные. Это окно, которое идет по последовательности сигнала? Это циклический сдвиг? Вроде, нет (в первом векторе есть три нуля подряд, во втором нет). Что для автора значит "совпадение"? А "вероятность совпадения"? Если это последовательности бит, то они или совпадают, или нет. Не понятно, при чем здесь вероятность.

Comment: во первых, автор не пытается найти четкое совпадение, о чем ясно указал (требуется найти начальную позицию и вероятность совпадения с образцом), во вторых - когда я начинал конкурс, то своим комментарием перевел вопрос в более общую плоскость - а именно, распознавание звуковых образов и в общем случае любых временных рядов сигналов

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, подобные "переводы в другую плоскость" нужно добавлять в вопрос, а не в комментарий к конкурсу